# Начинаю изучать JS. Вопрос по теме взаимодействия локальных и глобальных параметров объекта

Tags: javascript, функции, объекты

```js
function func(arg) {
    return arg = '!';
}

let obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
console.log(func(obj.a));
console.log(obj);
```

Меня интересует, почему в первом случае возвращает восклицательный знак вместо всего объекта, если я передавал только значение параметра объекта "а", при вызове функции.

Comment: Вы переданное значение заменили на ! и его же вернули. Вы какого поведения ожидали? Что хотели увидеть?

Comment: ожидал увидеть что-то вроде { a: ! , b: 2, c: 3};

Comment: Это я знаю, только мне хотелось бы услышать логику, почему передалось так, как целиковый объект.  Если в функции шло обращении к ключу, точнее при выполнении console.log(func(obj.a));

Comment: Потому что вы передали не ссылку на объект, а значение ключа **a** в объекте, т.е. в фукнцию пришло **1**...

Comment: Спасибо большое, все стало понятно!

Comment: @SwaD, а что изменилось бы передай он ссылку на объект?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Аргументы функций нужно рассматривать как обычные переменные.

Тогда твой код будет равносилен:

```
arg = obj.a;
arg = '!';
```

Очевидно, что в данном случае было бы странно ожидать изменение внутри `obj`.

Answer (score -1):

Потому что необходимо в функции просто возвратить аргумент

```
function func(arg) {
    return arg;
}
```